# How to avoid installing dependencies every time when creating a React app?

Tags: reactjs, npm, dependencies, create-react-app

When I use create-react-app to create a new project, it downloads and installs around 250 megabytes of dependencies each time. This takes a lot of time and uses a lot of my internet data.

I tried installing these packages globally, but it didn't work. I also thought about copying an existing React project folder, but it requires renaming and updating `package.json` for every project. **Is there any better way to avoid installing dependencies every time when creating a new React app?**

Comment: @EduardoYáñezParareda This is not a perfect solution for me, but in general it solves my problem, thanks!